# Cannot find module @angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling

Tags: angular, angular7, node-modules

I am trying to run angular project with `npm run start` command but getting this error:

> Cannot find module @angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling`.

Below is the result of `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.7
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4
```

package.json

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.7
@angular/cdk                      7.3.2
@angular/cli                      7.0.7
@angular/compiler-cli             7.2.16
@angular/material                 7.3.2
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.4
@schematics/angular               7.0.7
@schematics/update                0.10.7
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Comment: Have you run the npm install before npm run start?

Comment: @NaveenMotwani-AIS I ran npm ci as i need to ensure that packges are downloaded from packge-lock.json

Comment: Okay, you are also missing some packages, checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by clearing the cache using `npm cach clean --force` and reinstalling the dependencies using `npm init`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some package from angular eg @angular/core please compare your package.json file and add accordingly.

[image]

One more tip, remove package.lock.json file and then run npm install.

Comment: where should i compare these? what file should i open and compare? is packge-lock.json?

Answer (score 1):

`@ngtools/webpack` should be of a compatible with other packages version.

```
"@ngtools/webpack": "7.3.9"
```

should help

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules
2. update `@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.0` in **package.json**
3. make sure u have the correct node `@types/node": "^14.14.2` in **package.json**
4. finally `npm install`

This resolved the error for me

Answer (score 0):

#### Update angular/cli to the latest version

```
1- npm uninstall -g angular/cli
2- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

#### Update the project dependencies

```
1- rm -rf node_modules (or delete your node_modules folder manually)
2- npm cache clean (npm > v5 add --force so: npm cache clean --force)
3- npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
4- npm install
```